# How to define a keyboard shortcut in CLion for IdeaVim normal mode only?

Tags: clion, ideavim

For example, I am used to having `;` act as "fuzzy search file by name" (what Ctrl+Shift+N does) in Vim normal mode. So I go ahead and define this shortcut in settings; now I can't type `;` because it triggers file search even in insert mode.

Is there a way to define a CLion shortcut that works only in Vim normal mode, but not in insert mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to define mappings in IdeaVim is to use `~/.ideavimrc` file.
To define a mapping that works only in normal mode (and doesn't affect insert mode), you can use `nmap` mapping. You should add `nmap ; :action GotoFile<CR>` to your `~/.ideavimrc`.